# How to get the default position and font of UITableViewCell, using it in a custom cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to write an app which contains a table view with three cell, one custom cells and two "standard" cells

I have created a "custom cell" to be able to view a picture together with a subtitle in it. I would like to have the same look of the cell as a standard "UITableViewCell" but cannot figure out how to get the default position of "cell.textLabel.text". Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I would like to know as well. You can get close if not perfect by adjusting it one pixel at a time. It's just tedious!